# Is it possible to insert three different tables values in single insert statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables `table1`, `table2` and `table3`. I want to insert values into these three tables using a single `insert` query in SQL Server.

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not — and a simple 1 minute look at the syntax (which is in the documentation) would have told you.

It also is totally unnecessary as you can just issue 3 insert statements — and wrap them in a transaction to make them atomic.

Answer (score 0):

As MS SQL does not support Multi Table insert from single query(Oracle allow it), but I think you can use trick like, can write INSERT trigger on Table 1, Table2 and can execute Insert query for next table, as it would be ‘Single Session\Transaction’.

Thanks
Suresh